# How to display value having RIP relative address in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

I'd like to display an integer which lays in

```
global.variable+8(%rip)
```

How can I do it? And what exactly does this address mean? It's an address of `global.variable` + `%rip` + `8`, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global.variable+8(%rip)` is the address of `global.variable + 8`. It's just encoded in a RIP relative way in the instruction encoding.

In the example below, you can see that `global_variable+8(%rip)` refers to the same address as `*(((long long *)(&global_variable)) + 1)`:

### t.S

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

    .section .rodata
global_variable:
    .long 0x12345678
    .long 0x9abcdef0
    .long 0xdeadbeef
    .long 0x55aa55aa

    .section .text
    .global _start
_start:
    mov global_variable+8(%rip), %rax
    int $0x3 /* software breakpoint
                breaks into debugger */

    mov $SYS_exit_group, %rax
    mov $0, %rdi
    syscall
```

### t.gdb

```
file t
run

printf "rax: 0x%lx\n", $rax
set variable $gv1 = *(((long long *)(&global_variable)) + 1)
printf "global_variable[1]: 0x%lx\n", $gv1

quit
```

### Sample Session

```
$ gdb -x t.gdb

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
_start () at t.S:17
17      mov $SYS_exit_group, %rax
rax: 0x55aa55aadeadbeef
global_variable[1]: 0x55aa55aadeadbeef
```